# Can't compare specific positions in a list

Tags: c#

I was working on making a wordle bot to challenge my ability to program, but I am at a standstill.

```
List<string> wordsA = new List<string>();
List<string> letters = new List<string>();
letters.Add("");
wordsA.Add("");
if (letters[8] == "1")
{
   for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
   {
       wordsA.Add(words[i]);
       if (letters[7] == wordsA[4])
       {
          possiblewords1.Add(words[i]);
          wordsA.Remove(words[i]);
       }
                            
   }
}
```

Every guess, it breaks up the guess into 10 parts. For example, ERASE would  turn into E2R1A3S2E1, with the numbers representing if the letter was correct. And I was trying to compare "wordsA" to "letters". These are both lists. Almost every time it tries to check, I get the error

> Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
> of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
> collection. (Parameter 'index')    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)

This only occurs at the lines where it's comparing "wordsA" to "letters"

Comment: Your lists only have a single item.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about wordle, but the error is quite obvious... your `letters` list has one element - empty string. So, when you write `if (letters[8] == "1")` - your index is out of bounds